# Can I create multiple identity tables in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In my project, Admin adds Instructors, then each Instructor adds his students. When they are added, they'll receive an email asks them to complete registration .

I have the following classes in my project :

1-Student class

```
Student: int id, int Registry number, int grade, string password, string email, string name
```

2-Instructor class:

```
Instructor: int id, string name , string email , string password
```

3-My database context:

```
 public class InstructorContext:DbContext
{
    public InstructorContext() : base("InstructorContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }}
```

When a user loges in , I must determine whether he is an Admin or Instructor or Student. Do I have to use role-based authentication? I already have 2 separate classes for different roles. Is it possible for both of them to inherit from IdentityUser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you cannot have multiple user tables with Identity, at least not *technically*. All the other core components of Identity (roles, claims, logins, etc.) are setup with foreign keys to one user table.

For your scenario here, you should use inheritance. For example:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser

public class Instructor : ApplicationUser

public class Student : ApplicationUser
```

By default, Entity Framework will create the one table for `ApplicationUser` and add a `Discriminator` column to it. This column will have one of three possible values: "ApplicationUser", "Instructor", and "Student". When EF reads from this table, it will use this column to instantiate the right class. This is what's known as single-table inheritance (STI) or alternatively as table-per-hierarchy (TPH). The main downside to this approach is that all of the properties for all of the classes must be represented on the same table. If you're creating a new `Student` for example, the columns for an `Instructor` would still be on the record, only with nulls or defaults for those values. This also means that you can't enforce a property on something like `Instructor` be required at the database level, as that would prevent saving `ApplicationUser` and `Student` instances which are unable to provide those values. In other words, all your properties on your derived classes must be nullable. However, you can always still enforce something like a property being required for the purpose of a form using view models.

If you *really* want to have separate tables, you can somewhat achieve that goal by changing the inheritance strategy to what's called table-per-type (TPT). What this will do is keep the table for `ApplicationUser`, but add two additional tables, one each for `Instructor` and `Student`. However, all the core properties, foreign keys, etc. will be on the table for `ApplicationUser`, since that is where those are defined. The tables for `Instructor` and `Student` would house only properties that are defined on those classes (if any) and a foreign key to the table for `ApplicationUser`. When querying, EF will then do joins to bring in the data from all of these tables and instantiate the appropriate classes with the appropriate data. Some purists like this approach better as keeps the data normalized in the database. However, it's necessarily heavier on the query side because of the joins.

One last word of caution, as this trips people up constantly dealing with inheritance with Identity. The `UserManager` class is a generic class (`UserManager<TUser>`). The default instance in `AccountController`, for example, is an instance of `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`. As a result, if you use that instance, all users returned from queries will be `ApplicationUser` instances, regardless of the value of the `Discriminator` column. To get `Instructor` instances, you would need to instantiate `UserManager<Instructor>` and use that for your `Instructor`-related queries.

This is especially true with creating users for the first time. Consider the following:

```
var user = new Instructor();
UserManager.Create(user);
```

You might expect that the user would be saved with a discriminator value of "Instructor", but it will actually be saved with "ApplicationUser". This is because, again, `UserManager` is an instance of `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` and your `Instructor` is being upcasted. Again, as long as you remember to use the appropriate type of `UserManager<TUser>` you'll be fine.

Comment: If I have only 1 Admin , Do I have to add "Admin" class ? or is it enough to check for the email and password?

Comment: No. I mean you *could*, but "Admin" is more typically considered a role. A good way to draw a distinction is to consider overlap. If something like an `Instructor` could also be an admin (whether or not you're actually going to allow that), then it's probably better as a role. That way you *could* make an instructor an admin if you needed to, without effecting the rest of the system. Otherwise you'd end up with stuff like `Instructor`, `Admin` and `AdminInstructor`, which would obviously get messy very quickly,

Comment: Also, by using a role you can then add something like `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` to controllers/actions that are only for admins. As another derived type, you would need to create something custom to determine the level of access.

Comment: Oh sorry. I think I misread your question to begin with. You could technically have Instructor and Student as roles as well. I think it's better to have them as derived types because they're likely to have their own data. At the very least, it might be nice to have something like `ICollection<Student>` on your `Instructor` class, for example, which would not make sense for `ApplicationUser` or `Student`. Something like Admin is more of a special case that doesn't really imply a lot of specific data needing to be stored. It's more about privilege.

Comment: Sorry if I am asking a lot. I asked before if I should add ICollection<Student> to Instructor class, but someone said that I shouldn't. Since the instructor added them they'll be already associated to him. Is it correct?

Comment: Not unless there's still a relationship created. In other words, you could add an `Instructor` property to `Student`, and then forgo the `ICollection<Student>` on `Instructor`. However, all that does is just make it harder to get a list of students that belong to an instructor. You might has well keep the navigation property.

Comment: @ChrisPratt what about role table?? i try this and then try add role to another IdentityUser but it fail "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId"."

Comment: @AminM: that means that that role has already been added for the user.

Comment: @ChrisPratt but this happen when i try add new user!!!also this create new field 'AdminUser_Id' in my AspNetUserRoles where AdminUser : IdentityUser and another users class inherit from AdminUser

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. Most likely, you're not using view models as you should be and jacking up the entity change tracking. You should open a question.

Comment: @ChrisPratt i use ToTable("AspNetUsers") and its seems to work correctly now! if somthing get wrong i open new question,anyway tnx